# Diferenças entre glassfish 4.0 e Wildfly 8.0.0

Tags: glassfish, servidor-de-aplicação

1 - Há alguma diferença de desempenho e/ou complexidade de uso quando comparando os servidores de aplicação: Glassfish 4.0 e Wildfly 8.0.0?

2 - Há alguma situação especifica em que o uso de 1(um) deles é mais eficiente/interessante que o outro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markus Eisele fez um post bastante interessante no blog dele justamente com essa comparação. Apesar de eu ter achado a comparação um tanto superficial, acredito que você irá gostar de dar uma lida lá.

http://blog.eisele.net/2014/01/wildfly-8-vs-glassfish-4-which.html

Outros links interessantes relacionados a este tema:

- http://www.edgarsilva.com.br/blog/2008/09/26/porque-para-falar-de-glassfish-e-preciso-falar-mal-de-jboss-e-tomcat/
- http://blog.arungupta.me/2013/11/glassfish-commercial-is-dead-wildfly-and-jboss-eap-to-rescue/
- http://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/1wdxw0/wildfly_8_vs_glassfish_4/

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi dos links que você colocou na sua resposta, não há diferenças significativas que possam ser notadas nestes dois servidores de aplicação quanto a qualquer pergunta que fiz na questão, tanto que em um dos links que você postou é citado que o código-fonte deles são semelhantes. Significa que a escolha só depende do gosto do desenvolvedor.

Comment: Postei os links no intuito de que você formasse a sua própria opinião a partir das informações disponíveis. Respeito a sua opinião, mas devo dizer que a minha opinião é um pouco diferente da sua.

Comment: Vejo sim, algumas diferenças significativas entre eles (não necessariamente em quesitos técnicos, veja que há várias outras questões como estratégia de comercialização, suporte, serviços de consultoria, facilidade de contratar profissionais experientes na plataforma etc...).

Comment: Penso que para se tomar uma decisão acertada na escolha de um appserver para um projeto grande/complexo ou para ser o backbone de aplicações corporativas de uma empresa, tal escolha depende de vários fatores (alguns deles até já listei acima), não dependendo apenas do gosto do desenvolvedor e não existindo, portanto, uma resposta pronta e fácil para tal questão.

Comment: Entendo. Agradeço por expressar sua opinião.