# Diferenças entre servidores de aplicação Java

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, jboss, glassfish

Gostaria de saber quais são as principais diferenças entre os servidores de aplicação Glassfish, JBoss e Apache Tomcat. Há algum aspecto específico que eu devo verificar antes de escolher algum para iniciar o desenvolvimento? Há diferenças significativas de performance e segurança entre eles? A principal diferença que eu achei durante uma pesquisa foi que o Apache Tomcat não é servidor EJB...

Comment: O JBoss (somente o servidor de aplicação) não trocou de nome e virou Wildfly?

Comment: Renan, é verdade. Não sabia, obrigado!

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103109/o-que-é-o-jboss/103141#103141. Se não te esclarecer avisa.

Comment: @renan tava queimado demais? :)

Comment: @bigown não sei, nunca usei JBoss :P mas tem uma "explicação" [aqui](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/04/22/jboss_as_becomes_wildfly/).

Comment: @renan é, tava queimado :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JBoss(agora Wildfly) e Glassfish são servidores de aplicação homologados pela Oracle para dar suporte ao JEE(Java Enterprise Edition).

O Tomcat é um container de servlet e  oferece suporte parcial as especificações JEE, no caso Servlet, JDBC, JNDI e outras.

**Qual devo escolher?**

Caso o projeto seja todo baseado na JEE e use especificações que o Tomcat não oferece suporte nativo, como CDI JTA, EJB, JMS  é melhor usar o Wildfly ou Glassfish.

Existe essas perguntas que você também pode olhar:

[Diferenças entre glassfish 4.0 e Wildfly 8.0.0](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13516/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-glassfish-4-0-e-wildfly-8-0-0)

[O que é o JBOSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103109/o-que-%C3%A9-o-jboss/103141#103141)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821640/what-is-difference-between-tomcat-and-jboss-and-glassfish

Comment: Ótima resposta, há mais detalhes que possam ser acrescentados? Muitos optam pelo Wildfly pelo mesmo possuir essas especificações que foram citadas, porém percebi que o tempo de depois para o projeto depois de alterado algo pode ser demorado, com o Tomcat não percebi essa demora e parece ser mais leve inclusive. +1